# How make travis-ci execute for some branch?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I have a few branches in my repo and I have the `.travis.yml` file in a branch `A` (`master` branch does not have this file). But travis-CI is not starting the build for branch `A`. What do I need to do to run travis for this branch? When I create a Pull Request from some other branch to `master`, then travis starts the build.

P.S. I turned off/on `Build only if .travis.yml is present` but it did not help. Also I can't see any branches in `Branches` tab. I added

```
branches:
  only:
    -A
    -master
```

in the `.travis.yml`, but it too did not help.

Answer (score 36):

You can try and check if it would work with a whitelist.
See "[Specify branches to build](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#Specify-branches-to-build)"

You can either white- or blacklist branches that you want to be built:

```
# blacklist
branches:
  except:
    - legacy
    - experimental

# whitelist
branches:
  only:
    - master
    - stable
```

Try and put A in a whitelist syntax in the `travis.yml`, and see if that is picked-up.

Answer (score 6):

Your sample in .travis.yml is not yml compatible. You need put a whitespace before your branch names.

```
 branches:
  only:
    - A
    - master
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart for adding the whitelist branches,you can add a .travis.yml file to the branches of interest.

```
Note that for historical reasons .travis.yml needs to be present on
all active branches of your project.
```

You can get this from [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/)